# Hazelcast management center exception

Tags: hazelcast

Whenever I try to run the hazelcast management cluster I get the following error 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [collector] in context with path [/mancenter-3.4.2] threw exception
com.hazelcast.com.eclipsesource.json.ParseException: Expected value at 1:0

I am running hazelcast management center on tomcat 8.0. I am able to login without any issues but when I try to add any value to "Update Cluster URL" I get the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded `3.4.2` from hazelcast `website`.

Then i copied mancenter.war to tomcat8/webapps directory.

In `hazelcast-3.4.2` folder, there is demo folder and i executed `console.sh.`

When i put entries to map, i saw these entries also in mancenter.
I didn't encounter any problem.
My tomcat version `8.0.23`

When you try `tomcat7`, do you see errors?

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to version mismatch between your Hazelcast cluster and management center.
What's your hazelcast version?